# remove RTC control panel icon from desktop

Tags: windows-7

I have installed IBM Rational Team Concert Shell 4.0 using IBM's Installation Manager and without asking it placed an icon on my desktop. I hate desktop icons. besides, there's also a link to the RTC Shell in the start menu. so I tried deleting the icon but apparently that's not even possible.. when I right-click the icon the only options I get are "Open" and "Create shortcut". selecting it and pressing Delete also doesn't remove it. I tried looking for the icon in windows explorer so I could remove it there, but it's not in my user's desktop folder and Windows says I don't have access to the "all users" desktop folder. so, how do I get rid of the RTC Shell icon on my desktop?

PS: it's this icon

[image: rtc shell icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to hide the desktop icon this way: (Windows 7 but should work on XP)

navigate to: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace and identify the key (GUID) containing the Default REG_SZ named Rational Team Concert Shell

Copy the name of the key (GUID.. in my case it was {1632EAAE-5B6A-4861-AE2E-90BA389AF9BC} ) then navigate to the following location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel

create a new REG_DWORD Value that has the same name as the GUID noted earlier and give it 1 for Value Data

Refresh the desktop and the icon is gone...

Comment: The key name `...F9BC}` was the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to get rid of the icon while keeping the RTC Shell application.

- Open the registry editor and
- navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`
- look for a key that contains a string value named `(Default)` with value `Rational Team Concert Shell`.
- rename the `GUID` of the key or delete the key and press F5 on the desktop to refresh it.

The RTC Shell icon should now be gone.

**UPDATE:** apparently when you delete or rename the registry key the control panel will no longer start from the start menu either because that links to the RTC Shell on the desktop. AARGH!

Comment: Good to know. +1

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you simply select it with the mouse, and press delete, it will remove the icon on your desktop</del>.

I have RTC3.0.1 installed, and never had any issue removing that icon... because I never seen it!

The "Control Panel" for RTC is actually only present with RTC4: see "[Introducing the Rational Team Concert Shell integration for Windows Explorer](https://jazz.net/blog/index.php/2012/02/06/introducing-the-rational-team-concert-shell-integration-for-windows-explorer/) "

And it is directly installed in your folder (which is why you cannot delete it through the GUI, unless you uninstall that feature or tweak the registry, as [you report in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741549/6309), upvoted)

[image: RTC control panel tray]

> We’ve tried to make RTC Shell as integrated into the explorer as we could. At the same time, we’ve also tried to keep it simple and intuitive.
>   To that end, **there’s a Control Panel for RTC Shell that installs in your Desktop folder and opens right in your Windows Explorer**.
>   The Control Panel lets you manage your Jazz artifacts: you can get connected to the Jazz repository, perform source control operations, or work with a simple artifacts navigator. You can tailor your RTC environment via preferences. It comes with built-in help for ease of use.

Comment: I have RTC version 6 and it's there as well. Not just version 4 (for those coming to this since 2012). Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but you might want to follow the Jazz forum question for this, as well as the corresponding work items.

https://jazz.net/forum/questions/81518/how-to-remove-the-team-concert-shell-desktop-icon

https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=217699

https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=392801

... But here we are 5 years later and still no solution. I think RTC is no longer in development?